# How to set variable to other ctp file from an action in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP 3. My action is:

```
function OrderFromReseller($api_key) {
    $this->render('index');
    $this->loadModel('Psetting');
    $products = $this->Psetting->find('all');
    $this->set(compact('products'));
}
```

Here I render another ctp file called index.ctp. Now 'products' variable is undefined in index. How to set this variable to index.ctp file from this action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `$this->render('index')` last:-

```
function OrderFromReseller($api_key) {
    $this->loadModel('Psetting');
    $products = $this->Psetting->find('all');
    $this->set(compact('products'));
    $this->render('index');
}
```

`render()` tells Cake to generate the View so anything that follows will not get taken into account by the template as it has already been rendered.